# meteor send data to users

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to send data to multiple users that is entered through a form.

For example,

```
<form>
    <textarea id="textarea1" name="note"></textarea>
    <label for="textarea1">Note</label>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" button>
</form>
```

If I submitted this from user1 how will I make it available for user 2, 3, and 4 but not for user5. Ideally I would want another input for username and when submitted it'll show for the specified users.

Comment: will it always be those users who are permitted to see the data? perhaps consider adding a flag to the data and user2, 3, and 4 can subscribe to that field.

Comment: No it will be different. I'm publishing to different roles but the data will be created by the user dynamically

Comment: Are you wanting each user to have to opt-in to receiving this data, or is this something you want complete control over who sees it?  (e.g. user 5 can never see this data)

Comment: Something I would want a user to have complete control over who sees it.

Comment: is it a collaborated form editing or just each user has a form depending on the role of the users?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles package. Basically you can introduce different roles with different permissions. The role of each user is defined as part of his/her user account and in your Publish functions you can distinguish different roles and which data they are allowed to see.

When a user inserts data he could specify which roles are allowed to see it as parameters in the data collection. You can check these parameters in your subscribe function to see who is allowed to see it.